# Which has smaller training error?

Tags: regression

Consider two curves $\hat{g}_1$ and $\hat{g}_2$ defined by

$$ \hat{g}_1 = \operatorname*{argmin}_g \left((y_i - g(x_i))^2 + \lambda \int [g'(x)]^2 dx \right)$$

$$ \hat{g}_2 = \operatorname*{argmin}_g \left((y_i - g(x_i))^2 + \lambda \int [g''(x)]^2 dx \right)$$

As $\lambda$ gets larger, which curve $\hat{g}_i$ has the smaller training SSE? How about for testing SSE?

Answer (score 4):

For any fixed $\lambda$, this entirely depends on your data. But as $\lambda$ gets larger, the regularization term starts to dominate and your data becomes irrelevant, such that $g_1$ becomes the constant (first derivative zero everywhere) function that best fits your data, and $g_2$ becomes the affine (second derivative zero everywhere) function that best fits your data.

With no knowledge of your data generating process, $g_2$ will have the better fit in-sample because of the additional degree of freedom, while $g_1$ will better generalize given the estimator is more parsimonious, thus giving a lower testing SSE.

This is all assuming that the argmin is taken over all twice differentiable functions on the appropriate domain.

Comment: +1 This reply stands out for being pithy and correct.